# AJAX closing div because it feels like it

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a page with Bootstrap, and I'm grabbing some data from an XML file with AJAX. All the data is retrieved perfectly. But I'm trying to display it in the grid format Bootstrap has 4 columns wide, and those four columns are of course in a row. However for some reason, the row div is being closed after the first column inside it. 
The result looks like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
<div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">contents</div>
</div>
```

The code:

```
var i = 1;
var openrow = false;
$(data).find('ITEM').each(function(){
    var $item = $(this);
    if(i == 1 || i%4-1 == 0){
        var html = '<div class="row">';
        console.log("Start row at item "+i);
        openrow = true
    } else {
        var html = '';
    }
    html += '<div class="col-md-3">';   
    html += '<a href="project.php?id=' + $item.find('ID').text() + '">'; 
    html += '<div class="thumbnail"> <img src="images/'+$item.find('NAME').text().replace(/ /g, "_")+'_Preview.png" alt="'+$item.find('NAME').text()+' Preview" />';              
    html += '<div class="caption">'
    html += '<h3>' + $item.find('NAME').text() + '</h3>';                   
    html += '<p>' + $item.find('TYPE').text() + '</p>';
    html += '</div>'; //close caption
    html += '</a>';
    html += '</div>'; //close thumbnail
    html += '</div>'; //close col-md-3
    if(i%4 == 0 && i>1){
        openrow = false
        html += '</div>';
        console.log("End row at item "+i);
    }
    $('#content').append(html);
    i++;
});
if(openrow == true){
    $('#content').append('</div>');
    console.log("End row at item "+i);
}
```

And the console:

```
Start row at item 1
End row at item 4
Start row at item 5
End row at item 8
Start row at item 9
End row at item 11
```

Which is displaying perfectly fine as there are currently 10 items. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: @NicoFerna no the anchor tag is not out of place, I want any of the content inside the column div to link and it does it's job fine

Comment: Yeh, you're closing the `caption` then the `anchor` whilst the `thumbnail` div is still open

Comment: Dear person who marked as a duplicate, as the opening and closing tags are inside conditional statements the answers in the other question will not work here.

Comment: @Quentin The so-called "duplicate" you're referring to is completely unrelated. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The problem is identical - you are trying to append *tags* (e.g. `$('#content').append('</div>');`) instead of *elements*. The solution is identical — You build the complete HTML before appending any of it. It *is* a duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed. My bad. I missed the append at the end.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson you `edited` mine with an answer of your own so I rejected the edit and saved your content here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/AV2M5/

Comment: Ok so here is a suggestion on jsfiddle instead as this post was marked duplicate. http://jsfiddle.net/AV2M5/2/

Comment: @PabloKarlsson it is open again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend breaking out a few parts of your code into functions to make it clearer. the conditions you are using are quite complex and can be reduced in some cases. For instance:

```
i == 1 || i%4-1 == 0
// And this row are are equivalent
i%4-1 == 0
```

It also seems the order of closing the html elements has been a bit reversed the a should be closed after the thumbnail div.

Here is code that I think should work for you

```
var html ='';
 $(data).find('ITEM').each(function(index){
    if(i%4 == 0){

      if(i > 1){
        html += '</div>'; // Insert end if not first loop trough
      }

      html = '<div class="row">';
    }
  html +=  createInnerColumns($(this));
});
html += '</div>';
$('#content').append(html);

function createInnerColumns(item) {
  html += '<div class="col-md-3">';   
  html += '<a href="project.php?id=' + item.find('ID').text() + '">'; 
  html += '<div class="thumbnail">'
  html += '<img src="images/'+item.find('NAME').text().replace(/ /g, "_")+'_Preview.png" alt="'+item.find('NAME').text()+' Preview" />';              
  html += '<div class="caption">'
  html += '<h3>' + item.find('NAME').text() + '</h3>';                   
  html += '<p>' + item.find('TYPE').text() + '</p>';
  html += '</div>'; //close caption
  html += '</div>'; //close thumbnail
  html += '</a>';
  html += '</div>'; //close col-md-3
  return html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 1;
var openrow = false;
var runningHTML = '';
$(data).find('ITEM').each(function () {
    var $item = $(this);
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="col-md-3">';
    html += '<a href="project.php?id=' + $item.find('ID').text() + '">';
    html += '<div class="thumbnail"> <img src="images/' + $item.find('NAME').text().replace(/ /g, "_") + '_Preview.png" alt="' + $item.find('NAME').text() + ' Preview" />';
    html += '<div class="caption">'
    html += '<h3>' + $item.find('NAME').text() + '</h3>';
    html += '<p>' + $item.find('TYPE').text() + '</p>';
    html += '</div>'; //close caption
    html += '</div>'; //close thumbnail
    html += '</a>';
    html += '</div>'; //close col-md-3
    runningHTML += html;
    if (i == 4) {
        $('#content').append($('<div class="row"></div>').append(runningHTML));
        runningHTML = '';
        i = 1;
    } else {
        i++;
    }
});
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: In which case it's something to do with your modulo functions and the way you append unclosed tags. Will update answer.

Comment: The unclosed tags should be fixed in the version I added.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson submit your own answer.  Your `edits` are saved here http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/AV2M5/

Comment: Sorry rob I couldn't because it has been marked as duplicate. I still wanted to add the answer as It should help him.

Comment: Ok - Have also voted to reopen.  Hopefully you can submit your answer soon.  I can also `add` your edits but then the OP might give credit to me for your work!

Comment: It dosn't matter to me if you like to add my edits as your own.